# Javascript Regex doesn't match the recurring pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

```
Input:"[3, 4]", "[1, 2, 7, 7]"
Input:"[13, 4]", "[1, 2, 3, 6, 14]"
Input: "[5, 5]", "[1, 2, 3]"

\"\s*\[[0-9]\s*\,\s*[0-9]\]\"\s*\,\s*\"\[[0-9]\s*\,
```

This was what I tried to validate the above inputs. with what I tried I couldn't get the last part of the string validated. the second array of data can be any number of inputs.
The above regex applies until the first comma of the second array. couldn't now write a general expression for any number of inputs after that.

Comment: `the above inputs.` ... are they literally `"[3, 4]", "[1, 2, 7, 7]"` ... including `"` and `[]` - check [this](https://regex101.com/r/OXvRzu/2)

Comment: Yes they are. I checked the one you mentioned. but no. That is not it. I need the full string to be validated including all the "" [] and ,

Comment: I know ... I was showing you what yours does in a place you can fiddle with it and get it right :p

Comment: I use it to build regex. but the question was that I couldn't do the final part

Comment: OK, didn't realise, sorry to waste your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly

`^\s*"\s*\[\s*[0-9]+\s*(?:\,\s*[0-9]+\s*)*\]\s*"(?:\s*,\s*"\s*\[\s*[0-9]+\s*(?:\,\s*[0-9]+\s*)*\]\s*")*\s*$`

https://regex101.com/r/PpZy8I/1

```
 ^                  # Begin of string     
 \s*                # Leading wsp
 " \s*              # Quote start of array
 \[                 # Array opening
 \s* [0-9]+ \s* 
 (?:                # Optional nesting elements comma plus digits
    \, \s* 
    [0-9]+ \s* 
 )*
 \]                 # Array close
 \s* 
 "                  # Quote end of array    
 
 (?:                # Optional many more arrays
    \s* , \s* 
    " \s* 
    \[ 
    \s* [0-9]+ \s* 
    (?:
       \, \s* 
       [0-9]+ \s* 
    )*
    \] 
    \s* 
    "     
 )*
 \s*                # Trailing wsp
 $                  # End of string
```